# What could be practical examples of using finally in the try block in Python

Tags: python, try-finally

When does it make sense to use `finally` in the `try..except` block? Isn't listing statements just after the `try..except` doing the same?

What's the difference between these two?

```py
try:
    result = 100 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("division by zero!")
else:
    print("result is", result)
finally:
    print("final statement")
```

vs.

```py
try:
    result = 100 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("division by zero!")
else:
    print("result is", result)
print("final statement")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Isn't listing statements just after the try..except doing the same?

No, it isn't. You are assuming that you've covered all the ways the block can exit.

`finally` is guaranteed to be executed *even if the block is exited*. That includes `return`, `continue` or `break`, not only exceptions.

For your specific examples, you covered *almost* every possible path out of the `try` block. But you didn't cover `KeyboardInterrupt` or `MemoryError` however. If someone hits `CTRL-C` in the middle of execution, only for the first example would the `print("some code at last")` line be executed.

That's because your code doesn't catch `KeyboardInterrupt` or `MemoryError`, but those exceptions could still occur. If one of the exceptions was raised for the `result = 100 / 0` statement, then the exception would not be caught and the *whole frame would be exited*. But not before the `finally:` clause was executed.

It is easier to demonstrate with a different example, one which doesn't catch the exception raised:

```
mapping = {42: "The answer"}
try:
    result = mapping[42] / 17
except KeyError:
    print("Oops, no key 42 defined!")
else:
    print(result)
finally:
    del mapping
```

Here, the `finally` statement *will* be executed, even though the above raises a `TypeError` exception:

```
>>> mapping = {42: "The answer"}
>>> try:
...     result = mapping[42] / 17
... except KeyError:
...     print("Oops, no key 42 defined!")
... else:
...     print(result)
... finally:
...     del mapping
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
>>> mapping  # was deleted in the `finally` block
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mapping' is not defined
```

And that's what `finally` usually is used for, *to clean up resources*. You can even use it with `return` exiting a function:

```
>>> def foo():
...     try:
...         return 42
...     finally:
...         print("Returning doesn't stop finally from executing!")
...     print("This is never reached")
...
>>> foo()
Returning doesn't stop finally from executing!
42
```

Note that Python also has the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) and [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) to help do the same kind of work. Context managers *encapsulate* the clean-up usually done in `finally` and let you avoid having to look for the `finally` block at the end of a longer piece of code just to check if, say, a file is closed.

So instead of:

```
fileobj = open(filename)
try:
    with line in fileobj:
        # many lines of parsing code
        # .
        # etc.
        # .
finally:
    fileobj.close()
```

you can use file objects as a context manager and the above is simplified to:

```
with open(filename) as fileobj:
    with line in fileobj:
        # many lines of parsing code
        # .
        # etc.
        # .
```

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! Now it is more clear when and why to use the `finally` statement.